# Mongorestore not working (WiredTiger disk size error)

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

When I do mongorestore in MongoDB, I get the error "**WiredTiger error - No space left on device**" always with 54GB completed. But my disk is 400GB.
I already configured the **storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB** but it didn't help.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: "my disk is 400GB" - and how much is still free?

Comment: The error is related to the available free space on the disk. Although the disk size is 400GB - as @WernfriedDomscheit said, how much is available?

P.S. - Configuring CacheSize would not help the situation here in any way. It has nothing to do with the context of the use case as presented in the question

Comment: Hi. At the time of the crash, there were 345GB available. This is strange...

Comment: How much space is available on the **partition** where MongoDB stores the data?

Comment: @rickhg12hs 345GB in this partition.

Comment: What about logs, loglevel, etc.? Is there room for all that too, wherever they are going?